# padding-bottom displaying at nearly double size

Tags: css, padding

I have an issue with padding.  I added "padding: 30px" to the 'widgetdiv4' element and it looks as I hoped for the top and left but for some reason the bottom padding is nearly double and I have no idea why.   Here's the code:

```
<div class="large-4 columns" id="default_right">
<div id="rightsidebar" class="WidgetContainer">
    <div id="widget_16038" class="widget-menu-widget namenus-projects">
        <div class="widget basic widgetdiv1">
            <div class="widget basic widgetdiv2">
                <div class="widget basic widgetdiv3">
                    <div class="widget basic widgetdiv4">
                        <h3 class="widgettitle">Projects</h3>
                        <div class="menu_primary">
                            <ul>
                                <li class=" nested-menu-item"><a href="/"><span class="not-tc">Project 1</span></a></li>
                                <li class=" nested-menu-item"><a href="/"><span class="not-tc">Project 2</span></a></li>
                                <li class=" nested-menu-item"><a href="/"><span class="not-tc">Project 3</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="widget_16039" class="widget-menu-widget namenus-menu-widget">
        <div class="widget basic widgetdiv1">
            <div class="widget basic widgetdiv2">
                <div class="widget basic widgetdiv3">
                    <div class="widget basic widgetdiv4">
                        <h3 class="widgettitle">Menu</h3>
                        <div class="menu_primary">
                            <ul>
                                <li class=" nested-menu-item"><a href="/"><span class="not-tc">Link 1</span></a></li>
                                <li class=" nested-menu-item"><a href="/"><span class="not-tc">Link 2</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.widgetdiv4{
    padding: 30px;
}
ul, ol, dl {
      font-size: 1rem;
      line-height: 1.6;
      margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
      list-style-position: outside;
     font-family: inherit;
}
```

blessings!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to neutralize the browsers default styles. The reason why the bottom has more space is because it's inheriting properties from the generic `ul` .

Here's a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

It looks like this

```
         ul, ol, dl {
          font-size: 1rem;
          line-height: 1.6;
          margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
          list-style-position: outside;
         font-family: inherit;
```

Do this on your nested `ul` :

```
    .parentselector ul { margin-left: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px }
```